# What are the usage of extra available holes in model B

Tags: gpio, serial, connectors

Despite some research on the web, I cannot find the 
options available from these "opportunity" holes on 
the Rpi.

I probably do not use the proper words to identify them.

1. What is the name for this type of hole ?
2. What are the usage for the correspondence A, B C "opportunity" ?

[image: Available holes for extra connections]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you would call them P*-Headers, where the * designates which one exactly (5/2/3/6).

What you call Opportunity B is known as the P5-Header, and you can use it just like the GPIO-Pins next to it (see also [this link](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/raspberry-pi-p5-header/)).

Opportunity A (P6) can be used to reset your Raspberry Pi: Shorten it it reset. Be careful, though, as doing this while your SD-Card is active (writing) may damage the card.

Opportunity C consists of two separate Headers: P2 (closer to the GPIO) and P3 (closer to the USB/network connectors).

P2 is used during production of the board and is called "VideoCore JTAG", but cannot be used by the ARM processor.

P3 is called "LAN9512 JTAG" and is used by manufacturers to debug a device.

You can find some more information about so called "low-level-Peripherals" [here](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals).

Comment: Exactly info what I was looking for, this will help go further. Thanks

Comment: Note that the numbering of P5 is *from the **bottom** of the PWB* and it is just a *tiny* bit *too* close to the main GPIO header to fit a header easily in a completely upright position on the same side of the PWB as that main one!  I believe it was originally intended to be used with the first generation (26-Pin main GPIO connector - there is a later Cirrus Logic version for the A+/B+ and 2 RPis) [Wolfson Audio Card](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1803925.pdf) - interestingly *that* card uses 8 spring-pins and a mounting spacer to connect to P5 the "Audio GPIO" as they call it...!